# Spring controller, Jackson dataformat, and Azure blob storage v10

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-blob-storage, jackson-dataformat-xml

We have a quite big project based on Spring with an API returning json data by default.
As soon as we add the azure-storage-blob library dependency in maven pom, all the controllers instead of returning json by default, are returning xml.
I remove the dependency, and back to json.

Seems to be linked with Jackson dataformat, cause when I exclude it :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>10.3.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

goes back to json.... but azure does not work anymore :)

Do you have any ideas how to deal with that ?

Thanks and have a lovely day

Edit 2018-01-07 :
Jackson is an old friend, and I added spring configuration to force json as a fallback format, by it is not ideal:

```
@Override public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer conf) { 

    conf.favorPathExtension(true)
        .favorParameter(false)
        .ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
        .useJaf(false)
        .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}
```

This works partialy as some side effects are coming

Comment: Hello. I am stuck with the same problem, did you find a better solution, to avoid the side effects? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I haven't looked up for fallback, for now we don't have issues with this solution :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm not sure I follow...how did you fix the issue? I mean, you have Azure in your project, right? How did you make it work with JSON instead of XML? I haven't been able to find the right configuration, tried even creating a @Bean for ObjectMapper, but somehow I still see XML. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` per the Azure-storage-java [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java) it is what's used to parse data to Json. I'd also suggest checking this [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core) regarding Jackson core which may help as well.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I already looked at thoses, I edited my question with the last code changes